# Find the difference between a Time and 11 am on that day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have an `ActiveSuppport::TimeWithZone` object and I want to find out how many minutes after 11 AM on that day it is. So, for example, if the time is 11:47 AM, I want the answer to be 47.
Is there a way in Ruby/Rails to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Subtract and do math?

Comment: The time object can be for any day. I thought of extracting the hour and minutes and then subtracting 11 * 60 from that, but I was wondering if there was a better, more Rubyesque way.

Comment: if it's before 11 am is the answer negative or is it number of minutes since 11am the previous day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting one Time object from another gives the difference in seconds. Just divide by 60 to get minutes.

```
(mytime - Time.parse('11 AM')) / 60
```